# How to create toolbar with image?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, toolbar

I'm studying Window Desktop applicatin with C++, I'm trying create toolbar and add image *.bmp to toolbar button but them not appearance on toolbar.
I use `CreateToolbarEx()` and `TBADDBITMAP`.

My code:

```
TBBUTTON tbButtons[] =
    {
        { STD_FILENEW,  ID_FILE_NEW, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { STD_FILEOPEN, ID_FILE_OPEN, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { STD_FILESAVE, ID_FILE_SAVE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 }
    };
    HWND hToolBarWnd = CreateToolbarEx(hwnd,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_ADJUSTABLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
        ID_TOOLBAR, sizeof(tbButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON), HINST_COMMCTRL,
        0, tbButtons, sizeof(tbButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON),
        BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
        sizeof(TBBUTTON));

    TBBUTTON userButtons[] =
    {
        { 0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_SEP, 0, 0 },
        { 0, ID_DRAW_ELLIPSE,   TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 1, ID_DRAW_RECTANGLE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 2, ID_DRAW_LINE,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 },
        { 3, ID_DRAW_TEXT,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, 0, 0 }
    };
    TBADDBITMAP tbBitmap = { NULL, IDB_BITMAP1 };

    int idx = SendMessage(hToolBarWnd, TB_ADDBITMAP, (WPARAM) sizeof(tbBitmap) / sizeof(TBADDBITMAP),
        (LPARAM)(LPTBADDBITMAP)&tbBitmap);

    userButtons[1].iBitmap += idx;
    userButtons[2].iBitmap += idx;
    userButtons[3].iBitmap += idx;
    userButtons[4].iBitmap += idx;

    SendMessage(hToolBarWnd, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM) sizeof(userButtons) / sizeof(TBBUTTON),
        (LPARAM)(LPTBBUTTON)&userButtons);
```

Thank all.

Comment: Error checking?

Comment: `TBADDBITMAP::hInst` -- [_"Handle to the module instance with the executable file that contains a bitmap resource."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Commctrl/ns-commctrl-tagtbaddbitmap)

Comment: check the idx value not equal -1 to see whether the bitmap was added to toolbar successfully. And [this link](http://www.jgdprojects.co.uk/win32mixedtoolbar.htm) may also helpful for adding the icon to toolbar for your reference.